# Working with arrays and link lists - casting with integers and strings

Tags: c#

So I have programmed for about 6 months now and since it is break I am bored and playing around with stuff. I was going over the concepts of arrays again and made an array that produced 50 randoms numbers and used an insertion sort on them to put them in order. Then I started messing with string arrays. `string[] array = new string[] { "Ultima Online", "Everquest", "Baldur's Gate", "Diablo I"};` is my string array. To get it to display the entire string I used a linked list (which I am not sure if I had to, my attempts to casting it didn't work i.e Convert.ToString(array) failed). so I have this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] array = new string[] { "Ultima Online", "Everquest", "Baldur's Gate", "Diablo I"};
        List<string> list = new List<string>(array);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
    }
```

This displays the entire array. Then I thought what if I want to remove or add something to it. So, I placed `list.RemoveAt(2);` above my `Console.Writeline(list[i]);`

But this did something I didn't expect. It removes everything at and after the 2nd spot in my list. So I assumed RemoveAt() is going to always remove everything after that value that is indicated. 
However, `list.Remove(2);` gives my errors. 1. Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string' and then 2. The best overloaded method match...etc.. argument.
Again my casting didn't work. So, I reverted to RemoveAt and thought for a little bit. For some reason I thought if I make an if statement with an equivalent it would work, and it did.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] array = new string[] { "Ultima Online", "Everquest", "Baldur's Gate", "Diablo I" };
        List<string> list = new List<string>(array);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 2)
            {
                list.RemoveAt(2);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
```

So, my questions are these:
Why do the exceptions take place at Remove() but not RemoveAt().
Why does this if statement work? I took a shot in the dark at it and it works, I can understand why it works, but then not why a simply RemoveAt() wouldn't work.
Last, is there a better way to convert than a linked list?

Thank you for anyone who answers these question. I am new to programming and I am trying to understand some concepts that flew past me in my book and on MSDN.com and DotPearl...

Comment: You have a generic list of type `string`, not a linked list.  `RemoveAt()` removes the element at the specified index, `Remove()` removes the matching object from the List, and to work you need to implement `IComparable`.

Comment: Azzamean, better don't make assumptions and read documentations. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm slightly embarrassed at the linked list. I am reading exactly what one is right now. So that is a generic list of type string..Thank you much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RemoveAt` *only* removes the element *at that index*. It does **not** remove all the elements following it.

Unless.... you place it in a loop.

Which you did.

So your loop did this:

1. Remove element 2, output element 0
2. Remove element 2, output element 1
3. Remove element 2, output element 2
4. ... and so on

This "works" because of this:

```
for (.....; i < list.Count; ..... )
            ^-- this ----^
```

Basically, your loop and list looked like this:

1. List is "Ultima Online", "Everquest", "Baldur's Gate", "Diablo I" (4 elements, 0-based, elements 0 through 3)
2. Index is 0, Remove element 2, "Baldur's Gate", Output element 0, "Ultima Online"
3. Index is 1, still below length (which is now 3), so remove element 2, "Diablo I", output element 1, "Everquest"
4. Index is 2, which is now equal to length (which is now 2), so exit

You changed the list while enumerating over it, and you changed it *every iteration*.

The reason why `list.Remove(2)` doesn't work is because of this:

1. `list.RemoveAt(x)` specifies an index, and the element at that index is removed
2. `list.Remove(x)` specifies a value, and the first element in the list that has that value will be removed

Now in this case you have said the list is a list of strings, and you ask it to remove an integer. C#/.NET doesn't allow such shenanigans, and thus told you about the problem before even allowing you to run the program.

For more information, check out the documentation of:

- [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`List<T>.RemoveAt` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`List<T>.Remove` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: +1. I love an in-depth answer (pity I am lazy at this hour of the morning..) :)

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen This answered pretty much everything I was curious about. I am playing around on Visual Studios right now, again, thanks for helping someone new to programming.

Answer (score 3):

`Remove` takes a parameter of type `T` which corresponds to the object you want to remove. In your instance, `Remove` takes a `string` parameter which is supposed to correspond with one of the string items in your list (e.g. `Ultima Online`).

`RemoveAt` takes an int which corresponds to the *index* of the item in the list you want to remove. Once removed, everything is "shifted", so that what was at index 3 is now at index 2. When your loop passes over the `RemoveAt(2)` again, it removes the item that *is now* at index 2.

Answer (score 2):

`RemoveAt` works by index. `Remove` is using the types definition of equality. You have a `List<string>`, the type is `string`, string does character by character comparison to determine equality, to remove a string you need to do;

```
    list.Remove("Diablo I");
```

The issue with your `RemoveAt` getting rid of everything but the first item is well explained by Dave Zych's answer so I won't go into it.

I will talk about you converting to a list and your use of the term "Linked List" though. So firstly, `List<T>` in .NET is in no way a linked list. It behaved like one in some ways, however it is backed by an array. There is no need for you to convert to it. To print your array you could do either of the following;

```
  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
       Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
```

or

```
  Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", array));
```

You could easily "remove" an item by doing;

```
   array[i] = null;
```

Assuming you haven't done stuff like `string temp = array[i]` elsewhere before that line you would be setting the final existing reference to that string to `null` which basically puts in queue to be GC'd.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do the exceptions take place at Remove() but not RemoveAt()?

You get the exception `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'` because the method signature is `List<T>.Remove<T>(T)`. It expects a `string`.. and you're giving it a number.

> Why does this if statement work?

Because you're completely free to compare numbers with numbers. Again, you've used `RemoveAt` here.. which expects a number.. and you've correctly provided one.

Also, a `List<T>` isn't a linked list. It is in fact a list backed by an array. An important distinction imo.